# document reference in puppeteer evaluate/waitFor method

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am confused about the `document` reference in puppeteer `evaluate` method. The official doc has some code as follows. In the `waitFor` function, there is a document reference in the node script. I do understand that these lines are likely to be executed as: `waitForHandler.toString()` and then gets transfered to the browser environment to run via WebSocket connections. Anyhow, the document and some other variables such as window do cause confusions when they appear in the node script, don't they? Any explainations about this?

```
await page.waitFor(() => !!document.querySelector('.foo'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are very right, this might cause confusion.

**Example**

```js
const document = /* ... */;
await page.waitFor(() => !!document.querySelector('.foo'));
```

It looks like the code is accessing the variable `document` from above, but that's not actually what is happening here, even though your IDE/syntax highlighter might tell you its the same variable.

**Explanation**

The Node.js environment and the browser environment are two separate (JavaScript) environments that communicate via a WebSocket. Therefore, when you execute a function on the page inside your Node.js environment, puppeteer needs to send the function to the browser as a string. For this [puppeteer will call the `toString()` function](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/62733a20d726f2687e00fc42f3051e7767051755/lib/ExecutionContext.js#L88) on the given function which simply returns your high level code as you have written it down. That string will be sent to the browser and executed in its environment.

This is also the reason why you can pass a string to puppeteer instead of a function. If you submit a string instead of the function, the code will be executed as it is inside the browser environment.

To give an example for this, consider these two lines, which do the same (print `123` to the console):

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => 123));
console.log(await page.evaluate('(() => 123)()'));
```

In the first line, the function is passed as a function (and puppeteer will transform it into a string and call the function for you). In the second line, the same function is passed, but this time we have to call it on our own (the extra parenthesis around the functions are only needed for syntactic reasons).

**Why does it work like this?**

Puppeteer allows to pass the functions as functions (and not only as strings) for convenience. Allowing this, makes it easy to spot any minor mistakes like missing parenthesis as they are already picked up by your Node.js environment (your "Node.js JavaScript Parser" will still parse your function). Also it makes it easy to use syntax-highlighting in your code editor.

But yes, it's easy to forget that this abstraction layer means that any argument you use needs to be passed as a separate argument like this:

```js
const value1 = 123;
await page.evaluate((value1) => { /... */ }, value1);
```

To summarize, if you find it to confusing, you can always put your code into a separate file, read that file and pass its content as a string when calling puppeteer functions. This allows to separate your code better. Is it worth the effort? You have to decide that yourself...

Comment: Great explanation @thomas-dondorf ! I would expect this to be explained in Puppeteer's docs as one of the first things but atm having trouble finding anything on this :/